# Can't split a text file based on separator

Tags: bash, ubuntu, split

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have a text file named "group_keys", which contains a number of public keys that I'd like to split based on the delimiter

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and then output each key individually and sequentially. For example, if there are three keys, then the output would be three files with names like "person_1_key", "person_2_key", and "person_3_key".

The file looks like this:
[image]

I'm having difficulty using `split` and `csplit` to do this. The commands I'm inputting aren't working. Here's what I've tried;

#### Using split:

```
split --separator="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" group_keys
```

This doesn't output anything, but instead gives me the message

```
split: multi-character separator ‘-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----’
```

#### Using csplit:

```
csplit group_keys "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

This gives me only two files, "xx00" and "xx01", but it doesn't split the lines. "xx00" is completely blank, and the "xx01" is just the original file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
csplit -z -f person_ -b '%d_key' group_keys '/-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----/' '{*}'
```

which would output four files `person_0_key`, `person_1_key`, `person_2_key`, `person_3_key` where

- `-z` suppresses the generation of empty files
- `-f person_` sets the output filename prefix
- `-b '%d_key'` sets the output filename suffix
- `'{*}'` sets the repeat count (repeat as many times as possible)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

`awk '/-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----?/{n++}{print > "person_" n "_key" }' group_keys`

Comment: Yes, that indeed works! Thank you very much. However, could you please explain some of the syntax used? Particularly the text in enclosed curly brackets. I'm not familiar with AWK. Are those regular expressions?